# Parsley form not submitting

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I have created a form that is validates using Parsley.js and then submitted using php. The form is validating brilliantly, but it is not submitting to the php page: form_submission.php

The demo form can be found here http://tanujd.com/demop/contact-form.html ( i have pre-poppulated the form with dummy content to make it easier to test)

The HTML used is:

```
<form action="form_submission.php" id="contactform" method="post" data-validate="parsley">
<table width="200" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr class="name">
    <td>
        <label for="firstname">First Name*:</label>
        <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" data-trigger="change" required data-required="true" value="dummyfname" />
    </td>
    <td style="margin-left:10px;">
        <label for="lastname">Last Name*:</label>
        <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" data-trigger="change" required data-required="true" value="dummylname" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <label for="mobile">Mobile*</label>
        <input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" data-type="phone" data-trigger="change" required data-required="true" value="+1123456789" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <label for="email">Email* :</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" data-type="email" data-trigger="change" required data-required="true" value="dummy@emailid.com" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <label for="subject">Whats this about*:</label>
        <select id="subject" name="subject" required="required" data-required="true">
            <option value="1" selected="selected">Yey</option>
            <option value="2">Yey1</option>
            <option value="3">Yey2</option>
        </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <label for="category">Subject:</label>
        <input type="text" id="category" name="category" value="Dummy Subject" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <label for="message">Tell us about it*</label>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" data-trigger="change" required data-required="true">Dummy Text</textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" id="formid" name="formid" value="contactusform" />
        <input class="button" name="submit" type="button" value="submit" onClick="javascript:$('#contactform').parsley( 'validate' );" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

The PHP Code in the page: form_submission.php (The file online obviously has my proper email address)

```
<?php
$formid = $_POST['formid'];

$email_to = "myemailaddress@goeshere.com";

$first_name = $_POST['firstname']; // required
$last_name = $_POST['lastname']; // required
$mobilenum = $_POST['mobile'];
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form Submission: ". $_POST['subject'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
//$categoryselect = $_POST('category').value();
$message = $_POST['message']; // required

echo($email_from);

$email_message = "Submission details below.\n\n";
$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Mobile: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Whats this about: ".clean_string($subject)."\n";
$email_message .= "Category: ".clean_string($category)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";
$email_message = wordwrap($email_message, 70, "\r\n");

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
            'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message,$headers) or die("Error!");

echo "Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon. \r\n";
?>
```

The page validates fine, but it just does not go to the PHP page, and submit the form.
If i load the php page as is, it emails me a blank message (so basically the php form submitter is working)

Any idea how i can fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change type="button" to type="submit"

Write

```
<input class="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" onClick="javascript:$('#contactform').parsley( 'validate' );" />
```

instead of

```
<input class="button" name="submit" type="button" value="submit" onClick="javascript:$('#contactform').parsley( 'validate' );" />
```

Comment: Thanks, you can except as answer

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately you answered so quickly, that its under the minimum wait time before an answer can be selected. :). As soon as its done i will accept it.

Comment: Dude awesome! This helped me debug a weird issue that arose